# Array stringification with toString() and join()

Tags: javascript

It looks that for arrays `toString()` output is equal to `join()`, at least for some modern browsers,

```
arr + '' === arr.join(',')
```

Moreover, it appears that `join()` is called by `toString()` internally,

```
Array.prototype.join = () => 'foo';
arr + '' === 'foo';
```

Is it safe to assume that this behaviour is consistent among all browsers? Is it standardized?

Comment: Yes. It will behave same in all browsers. [Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2) and [MDN-Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString?v=control)

Comment: A slightly more modern version of the spec is [*ECMAScript 2016*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring), there are some significant changes (e.g. "*Whether the toString function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.*" has been removed). ;-)